# Ignore specific friend published messages in Facebook News Feed

Tags: facebook

How to ignore my specific friend published messages in my News Feed on Facebook and at the same time I don't want to unfriend with him.

Comment: Unsubscribe them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to their profile and remove "Show in News Feed" by rolling over the subscription button to the left of the message button

[image: News Feed Settings]

Comment: you are awesome,but how can you know this, where can i find the manual or they are still on the fly

Comment: Most of Facebook features are within facebook.com/help, the rest you can find by experimenting and reading the various Facebook official pages or doing as you did asking the question on a unofficial community site.